# Root crontab not running

Tags: root, cron, debian

For some reason, my root crontab does not seem to be running.

Trying to reboot the device every night at midnight.

Should be the following as root:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add:

```
0 0 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

When I test using some values close current time, nothing happens. I installed NTP and made sure the time zone is correct. I am also specifying using the 24-hour clock. For example, to test this line right now (5:35 PM) I try entering the following:

```
36 17 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

I have checked the time with date -R. The time for the crontab to run comes and goes and the system does not reboot. What am I missing here?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are closing the crontab after editing it, right? Also, how did you "run as root"? What is the output of `sudo crontab -l | grep -v '#'`?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:debian]? If this is about Debian and not Ubuntu, please ask on [unix.se].

Comment: Because debian is at the core of Ubuntu I believe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have three solution suggestions for you.

1. Invoke the crontab with `crontab -e -u root`
2. Make sure that you have an empty line at the end of the cronjob file, meaning that every line ends with a newline.
3. You might need to redirect the output to devnull: `shutdown -r now > /dev/null`

Here are two helpful webpages for cronjobs:

[CronDrive tester](https://www.crondrive.com/test-cron-expression?expression=0+2+%2A+%2A+%2A)

[Cron expression generator](https://crontab.cronhub.io/)

You can also handle the cronjobs neatly with [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/).

Other than that, you have at least two more ways for restarting your computer at midnight.

One is to run the shutdown command as a script automatically at login but with specific time as a parameter instead of "now":

`shutdown -r 00:00`

However, this will yield a broadcast message of upcoming shutdown at every login (might not be a bad thing at all). Well you can also make this be run at boot time by adding the script in init.d, still yielding the message, though.

Another is to use `at`command:

`at 0am`

Enter command `shutdown -r now` and save it with ctrl+d or do a script for the command and do:

`at -f restart_script.sh 0am`

Comment: The solution was to output to dev null. I wonder why?

Comment: It is because cron job has its own environment which does not have such a standard input/output system you'd expect and the process fails because it is trying to stream messages into a missing output pipe. Cron job is actually a lot different thing compared to running some command in terminal as any user. Glad to hear that you got it working after all.

Answer (score 1):

System Cron jobs are listed in /etc/crontab file. Therefore editing this file directly will help you out to run the reboot command as root.

therefore,

```
$ sudo vi /etc/crontab

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
  23 20 *  *  *  root  shutdown  -r  now
```

**make sure you check the Cron log file after editing the crontab as it will let you know if the cron was installed successfully.**

I have tested it and it worked for me. Restarted my system at 8:23 PM

Good LUCK!